# Setting Up My first network Labs?

Tags: virtualization, kali-linux, dhcp

so i'm a complete newbie to this field, but i'm using this book - 'Metasploit The peentration Tester's Guide' - by David Kennedy, etc.

I'm attempting to set up the virtual labs needed in order to actual proceed. However i'm stuck on the DHCP server instrucion. in the book its not very clear to me. But it says i need to install it.

I'm just wondering if the DHCP server needs to be installed on the Kali machine i will be using to get into the other virtual machines, or do i need to install it on the vulnerable virtual machines?

Furthermore the book told me to follow this guide online - http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/DHCP-Server.html

However when i try to install the server on kali linux - apt-get install dhcp3-server i get this error : E: package 'dhcp3-server' has no installation candidate.

Just wondering what i'm doing wrong here? As im not sure how to install this without this error, and if i'm even installing it on the correct virtual machine? Thank, any guidance is really appreciated.

Are there any updated guides to help me through this?

BTW i have already updated the Kali repositories.

Comment: You are asking how to set up a DHCP server.  Since you are asking about basic setup only instead of any security relevant parts this has nothing to do with information security, i.e. is off-topic here. It it does no get on-topic just because you are using Kali Linux for it. It has also nothing to do with penetration tests (tag removed).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use isc-dhcp-server. Read the manual for info on options and blocks in the configuration file. You may just as well use unbound, or dnsmasq. I recommend dnsmasq, it's very versatile.